# When using Apple's phased release of an app, which version is presented to users downloading for the 1st time?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Apple recently started offering phased app releases details [here](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process) where people with automatically updating turned on the app is based out in this manor. 1% gets the app on day one 2% on day 2, 5% day 3 etc. Based on the description I would expect that new downloaders would get the "old" version of the app until apples phasing roll out is complete (or the developer chooses to release to 100%).

Can anybody confirm this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New users will always see the **newest** version, they will not see the 'old' version.

From the [docs](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Submission%20Process).

```
All users will still be able to manually update your 
app directly from the App Store and new customers will 
always see your most recent Ready for Sale version.
```

Additionally, if a user updates manually, they will get the newest version as well. The only case they get the 'old' version is part of an automatic update.

Comment: Hmm I missed that part not what I would have expected, so I am really only protecting my "current" users with auto update turned on, not new downloads ... Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: To summarize;  1.All, 100%, New customers get the new version, ; 2.All  Old customers with Off = Settings / iTunes / Auto Download / Updates will continue seeing the old version with no prompts; 3.A phased percentage of Old customers with On =  Settings / iTunes / Auto Download / Updates will get the New; 4.New can be manually downloaded. https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev3d65fcee1

Comment: Are we sure new users always get the new version? This text can't be found in the documentation anymore (see link from AnneTheAgile above), nor is there any equivalent formulation that would indicate how new users are treated. (I'll submit a suggestion to Apple support to add a sentence about new users, even if they are treated the same way as existing users.)

Comment: The language could be clearer but yes - users should still always get the new version. These users are 'downloading' the app instead of 'updating' the app, and phased releases only concern automatic updates. ("Keep in mind that all users who have downloaded your app will still be able to update your app manually  from the App Store at any time." from https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1. The language could be clearer, but new users still always get the newest version.